# Show previous visited drop down menu item color different than other menu items.

Tags: css

I have a drop down menu based on CSS. Suppose there are 5 menu items at top level, when we hover on them show a drop down. My requirement is if I hover on menu item# 3 and select something from it then I will hover on menu item# 1 then menu item# 3 color need to be different in comparison to other menu items. 
Please let me know how to do the same.

Comment: What is the current progress with the code?

Comment: I can't share my code. Please share your opinion of any samples that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to use the `:visited` selector in your css. Hard to give specifics without you providing some code, but this is the general idea:

```
a:visted {
    color: orange;
}
```

You can go [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp) for an example.  That link also contains examples for other related selectors which might be useful to you, such as `:hover`